# Is there a benefit of picking an archetype?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

I have played through Shadowrun Returns as a Street Samurai and a Mage, but I noticed that most if not all of the archetypes have their stat points spread out and have a few points put in stats useless for them (i.e a Will Power for Street Samurai and Decker, or Strength for Shaman and Mage.

I am considering starting as a custom class and allocate the stat point myself. Is there any disadvantages to starting the game this way?

Comment: There are custom classes? o_O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no disadvantages, unless you choose to allocate skills poorly. The archetypes are just designed to be relatively safe choices that give you both flexibility and a core strength. If you are familiar with the system you can probably make a stronger character by customizing, it becomes a matter of player skill and playstyle.

Comment: When I tried playing a custom class and follow the Mage path, I was forced to play through the beginning sequence with no spells and had to relied on my crappy ranged weapon skills (which I purposely did not put points in). It was quite a while before a shop became available, and I had to fork out what little cash I had for a few low level spells. Do this lack of starting equipment put you off playing, for example, a custom Rigger? (Since the free drone you get when starting as the Rigger archetype cost 1k in shop)

Comment: On some campaigns you will have to limp through the starting area, yes. However, I think that this is (somewhat) intentional. The game is trying to teach you that a character should not be completely incompetent at everything but casting spells or rigging, or at least that doing so is hard, and it should be.